# Js: Make a div appear in all slides each time scrolling within sections and returning to slide section

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I use Fullpage plugin and sliders for my webpage.

I make a div appear with animation in sliders each time user scroll the page or change sliders.
But when I change slide, than scroll the page and back to slide section, div is dissapearing.

To find the problem:

1. Refresh the page, scroll within sections, the div appears in slide
   section during scroll down, up...
2. back to slide section, change the slide with arrow, div appears in
   2nd slide too
3. The issue:  scroll the page again and return to second slide, you
   can see that div disappeared.

If there is solution with Fullpage callbacks, that would be great, if not, any other solution will be acceptable.

JS:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
   scrollBar: true,
  scrollingSpeed: 300,
  touchSensitivity: 5,
  paddingTop: '52px',
  sectionSelector: '.section-content',
  slideSelector: '.slide',
  afterLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex) {

  if (index == 2) {
    $("#section1").find('.features-img').eq(0).addClass('show-zoom');
    $('#section1').find('.features-img').eq(slideIndex).addClass('show-zoom');
        }
        },
  onLeave: function (anchorLink, index, slideIndex) {
   if (index == 2) {
   $("#section1").find('.features-img.show-zoom').eq(0).removeClass('show-zoom');
   $('#section1').find('.features-img.show-zoom').eq(slideIndex).removeClass('show-zoom');
                    }
                },
afterSlideLoad: function (anchorLink, index, slideAnchor, slideIndex) {
   if (index == 2) {
      $("#section1").find('.features-img.show-zoom').removeClass('show-zoom');
      $('#section1').find('.features-img').eq(slideIndex).addClass('show-zoom');
                    }
                }

            });
```

Css:

```
.features-img {
  position: relative;
}
.zoom-img{
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale3d(0, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0;
  border: 4px solid #00b8e6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -80px;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
.show-zoom .zoom-img {
  -webkit-transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0.58, 0.58, 1) 0s, opacity 0.8s linear 0s;
  opacity: 1;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/maaqms8s/4/

Comment: You are being way too specific with your question. Simplify the question and make a basic example for it. Do not talk about `show-zoom` or `features-img`. Tell us what problem are you having with the callbacks and what would you expect. But don't tell us about your project specifics. Be abstract and basic. We don't need to know what those classes do.

Comment: Thanks for comment,  the classes just make understandable the parts about which I'm talking and the way I achieved that. Btw I have edited my question and described the steps (see "To find the problem" part).(after scroll and back, div appears on first slide thanks to afterLoad, onLeave and afterSlideLoad, but don't appear on 2nd, 3th ,4th slides). You can see this in fiddle too. Thanks for help

Comment: You are not describing the problem with the fullpage.js callbacks but your own specific problem with your classes, your elements etc. Not everybody has the patience or time to try to understand your problem. But what we can do is try to understand what you expect from the plugin callbacks or what you think fullpage.js is not doing right. That's the way you will get more answers. Good luck!

Comment: As you can notice I haven't say anything about fullpage.js issues. That's why I use SO, not open an issue in Github! I use the plugin, I like it but have Specific problem! If anybody don't have patience or time to read,  can just ignore my question! I have updated my question a bit, hope now the problem is understandable. Thanks for your time btw

Comment: You keep focusing on your particular scenario and not in the problem itself. (eg, a class needs to always be added when...). Just trying to help you to get answers.

Comment: Yup, that's why I edited my question. Thanks))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in `eq(0)`, it's add and remove class only on first slide, but you need to add/remove it on `current` slide. You already have `active` class on current slider, so you can use it.

Just edit a bit your code and the issue will be solved.

```
    if (index == 2) {
$("#section1").find('.slide.active').find('.features-img').addClass('show-zoom');
$('#section1').find('.features-img').eq(slideIndex).addClass('show-zoom');
 }
  if (index == 2) {
     $("#section1").find('.slide.active').find('.features-img').removeClass('show-zoom');
 $('#section1').find('.features-img.show-zoom').eq(slideIndex).removeClass('show-zoom');
}
```

Everything else seems ok.

Comment: That's great! checked lots of times, didn't pay attention on it. Thanks a lot